# Props "onChange" in Field Component doesn't fire the given function

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Using the component Field of redux-form, I am trying to display the length of the string written in the input. But it seems like the handleChange function is never fired by the onChange. 
Here is the component :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field} from 'redux-form';

var  max_chars = 160;
var LimitedCharsField = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            chars_left: max_chars
        };
    },
    handleChange(event) {
        var input = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            chars_left: max_chars - input.length
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Field name="short_description" id="short_description" component={this.props.renderSmallTextField} type="text"
                       label="Qualification du site" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} maxLength={max_chars}/>
                <br/>

                <small id="short_description_countdown" >{this.state.chars_left} caractères restants</small>

            </div>
        );
    }
});


export default LimitedCharsField;
```

And I am calling in a parent component which is the main form:

```
<LimitedCharsField renderSmallTextField={renderSmallTextField}/>
```

The component does appear in the form but the handleChange dosen't fire at all.

What should be done in order to get the function handleChange fired?

Many thanks.

*Edit: Below the renderSmallTextField*

```
const renderSmallTextField = ({input, label, meta:{touched, error}, ...custom}) => (
    <TextField
        hintText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        {...custom}
    />
);
```

Comment: React itself recommends either rebinding event handlers in the constructor i.e. `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` or using ES6 arrow functions i.e. `handleChange = (event) => {...}` have you tried either? Read: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Tried the rebinding way and the ES6 arrow, doesn't work. I also tried a simple function onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}. Doesn't work too ! Honestly, this is beyond my comprehension...

Comment: did you remember to remove the bind from the `render` function?

Comment: @TylerSebastian yes I did remember to remove the bind when using the ES6 arrow.

Comment: you need to remove it in both cases.

Comment: Are you using `redux-form v6.5.0`? Because that's when the `onChange` event handler stuff was introduced.

Comment: I was using the 6.4.smth version. I updated it and it worked.. At this point I am a little ashamed that it was that obvisous..  Thank you Erik Ras redux-form is really helping me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is because the onChange prop isn't passed around correctly. Couldn't say for sure without seeing the code for the `renderSmallTextField` component though. Try setting `component="input"` as a simple test. If the handleChange method starts firing you have found your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated my question with the renderSmallTextField. I changed the component value to "input" but the function didn't fired either..